# Create Empty CloudBlockBlob in Azure

Tags: java, azure

I'm hoping the answer to this question is quite simple, but I can't get it working after looking at the Azure Java API documentation.

I am trying to create an empty CloudBlockBlob, which will have blocks uploaded to it at a later point. I have successfully uploaded blocks before, when the blob is created upon the first block being uploaded, but I can't seem to get anything other than ("the specified blob does not exist") when I try to create a new blob without any data and then access it. I require this because in my service, a call is first made to create the new blob in Azure, and then later calls are used to upload blocks (at which point a check is made to see if the blob exists). Is it possible to create an empty blob in Azure, and upload data to it later? What have I missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not worked with Java SDK so I may be wrong but I tried creating an empty blob using C# code (storage client library 2.0) and if I upload an empty input stream an empty blob with zero byte size is created. I did something like the following:

```
        CloudBlockBlob emptyBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("emptyblob.txt");
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            emptyBlob.UploadFromStream(ms);//Empty memory stream. Will create an empty blob.
        }
```

I did look at Azure SDK for Java source code on Github here: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-api/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/blob/client/CloudBlockBlob.java and found this "upload" function where you can specify an input stream. Try it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: I use this method to upload my blocks, but I guess I didn't think to use an empty stream as a way of initialising. Works great, cheers!

Comment: @SirSlush86  Can you provide more details for  created empty CloudBlockBlob ?